# CC field not being applied in CakeEmail

Tags: email, cakephp

I have two emails that get sent out, and both are called in a similar fashion. However, there is one major difference: For one of them, the recipient of the CC gets the email, and for the other she does not. I have absolutely NO idea what might be causing this behavior, since they appear to be exactly identical otherwise.

This is the code used to create the email that DOES get the CC applied properly:

```
public function sendEmail($order = array(), $account = array(), $member = null) {
    $email = new CakeEmail();
    $email->template('order', 'default')
            ->helpers(array('Html'))
            ->viewVars(array('order' => $order, 'account' => $account, 'member' => $member))
            ->emailFormat('html')
            ->to($account['Account']['email'])
            ->cc('katherine@thecommunitycoop.org')
            ->from('general@thecommunitycoop.com')
            ->subject('Your order for '.$order['Sale']['sale_date'])
            ->send();
```

This is the code used to create to create the email that is NOT getting the CC:

```
public function pendingEmail($order = array(), $member = false, $success = true) {
    $email = new CakeEmail();
    $email->template('pending', 'default')
            ->helpers(array('Html'))
            ->viewVars(array('order' => $order, 'member'=>$member, 'success' => $success))
            ->emailFormat('html')
            ->to($order['Account']['email'])
            ->cc('katherine@thecommunitycoop.org')
            ->from('general@thecommunitycoop.com')
            ->subject('Your order for '.$order['Sale']['sale_date'])
            ->send();
```

As you can see, the cc field is identical. Both emails are getting sent to the 'to' field correctly; it is only the cc field that is not working properly on the second one. What could possibly be causing this behavior?

Comment: Don't get me wrong but you say that according to the recipient she does not receive the second email yet the code is virtually the same. Did you try putting your e-mail address in the BCC field to confirm the user's complaint?

Comment: Weird, if the code is almost the same... Have you tried sending the mail directly to the CC mail account and see if she gets it? Did she check spam?

Comment: I haven't tried the BCC field, and won't get a chance until next time the code runs, but I have looked at the user's email. The emails are not being sent to spam either.

The emails are generated the same way, but they are being called from different places. The first email is called when someone places an order online. The second email (the one not getting sent to CC) is called when "pending" orders get processed once a week. The process runs each order automatically and sends a call to a function which commits the order and generates the email. Is there any reason this would affect CC?